# Peano arithmetic vs. fast-growing hierarchy with pathological fundamental sequences

Tags: lo.logic, proof-theory, ordinal-numbers, ordinal-analysis

Fundamental sequence for a countable limit ordinal $\alpha$ is an increasing sequence $\{\alpha[i]\}$ of ordinals of length $\omega$ such that $\lim_{i\rightarrow\omega}\alpha[i]=\alpha$. There are many (continuum many, in fact) possible choices for fundamental sequence for any ordinal, some are quite natural, like $\omega^2[n]=\omega n$, and some are quite odd, like $\omega[n]=\Sigma(n)$. Most common definition of fundamental sequences below $\varepsilon_0$ is via Wainer hierarchy. Using these, it's known that in fast-growing hierarchy, $F_{\varepsilon_0}(n)$ is a total recursive function which outgrows all recursive functions which Peano axioms can prove total. A friend of mine posed a question, if this necessarily hold under different choices for fundamental sequences. For me, it seems like the answer would be *no*, because we can choose some very slow fundamental sequences for all ordinals, possible making it slower than $F_\alpha(n)$ for some $\alpha<\varepsilon_0$ in Wainer hierarchy, but my friend believes the answer to be *yes*.

To put it into a single question:

> Is it true that for any choice of fundamental sequences for ordinals below $\varepsilon_0$ we have that, in fast-growing hierarchy, $F_{\varepsilon_0}(n)$ outgrows all functions provably total recursive in PA?

Does it make any difference if we replace it with Hardy hierarchy?

Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: This type of phenomena has been studied by Andreas Weiermann and several co-authors as _phase transitions_; e.g. http://hdl.handle.net/1854/LU-547642 examines when the Ackermann function ceases to be non-primitive recursive.  The answer to your question might appear in one of the related papers.

Comment: When I am remember things correctly one can use the definition $\lambda\{x\}:=\lambda[\log^*(x)]$ where $\log^*$ refers to the inverse tower function to obtain the desired negative result for the Hardy hierarchy. I assume that one even can modify the definition to work for strictly increasing fundamental sequences.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is no. Choose a fundamental sequence for $\epsilon_0$ itself in the usual way, which I think is $\epsilon_0[n]=\omega^{\omega^{{\vdots}^\omega}}$, and then modify the earlier fundamental sequences for $\alpha=\epsilon_0[n]$ by making it start with $0,1,2,\ldots,n$, before resuming with the usual values. In particular, we have thereby ensured $\alpha[n]=n$ for $\alpha=\epsilon_0[n]$. It now follows, according to the rules of the [fast-growing hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast-growing_hierarchy), that $F_{\epsilon_0}(n)$, which by definition is $F_{\epsilon_0[n]}(n)$, is the same as $F_\alpha(n)$ where $\alpha=\epsilon_0[n]$, but since this is a limit ordinal, it is equal to $F_{\alpha[n]}(n)$, which is the same as $F_n(n)$, by construction. So with these modified fundamental sequences, the top function $F_{\epsilon_0}$ is basically the same as $F_\omega$. This seems completely to confirm your intuition that slowing the fundamental sequences down could make the diagonal function at the top very small.

If we dropped the requirement that the fundamental sequences must be strictly increasing, we could pad with $n$ many $0$'s instead, ensuring that $\alpha[n]=0$ for limit $\alpha=\epsilon_0[n]$, and get a more extreme situation $F_{\epsilon_0}(n)=F_{\epsilon_0[n]}(n)=F_{(\epsilon_0[n])[n]}(n)=F_0(n)$.

Comment: I think you want $\alpha\ge\epsilon_0[n]$, not the other way round. The way it is written, you force all the fundamental sequences to be just the sequence of all natural numbers, which doesn’t converge to $\alpha$.

Comment: Yes! I'll edit straight away.

Comment: I have edited. It seems that I actually just need to modify the sequences at the ordinals $\alpha=\epsilon_0[n]$ themselves, and the others can be left alone.

Comment: This is the best answer I could hope for! It's not only extremely simple, but modifies only very little number of fundamental sequences. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad you like it. It is an interesting question, which confused me at first, until I could see my way through.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Do you think we could make a similar construction, so that we also have, for all ordinals $\alpha<\beta\leq\varepsilon_0$, that $F_\alpha$ is eventually outgrown by $F_\beta$? (that is, for sufficiently large $n$, $F_\alpha(n)<F_\beta(n)$? Your construction satisfies it for all ordinals other than $\varepsilon_0$ itself.

Comment: I only modified finitely much of any given sequence, and so my modification can't affect this kind of tail event property.